# Why was the dyn syntax introduced?

Tags: syntax, rust, keyword

In [Rust 1.27.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/06/21/Rust-1.27.html) a new syntax is introduced - the `dyn` keyword was added.

```
  // old => new
  Box<Foo> => Box<dyn Foo>
  &Foo => &dyn Foo
  &mut Foo => &mut dyn Foo
```

What does it actually do and why was it added?

Answer (score 48):

This helps differentiate between traits/trait objects and structs; `&Foo`, `Box<Foo>` and `impl Bar for Foo` were ambiguous, because in all of them `Foo` could have been a trait or a struct.

With the addition of `dyn` this is no longer ambiguous, as traits are distinguished by the `dyn` keyword:

```
// trait objects (new dyn syntax)
&Foo     => &dyn Foo
&mut Foo => &mut dyn Foo
Box<Foo> => Box<dyn Foo>

// structs (no change)
&Bar
&mut Bar
Box<Bar>
```

Comment: Are there any cases where traits shouldn't gain the `dyn`?

Comment: @NicHartley only if they are not used as trait objects; otherwise, no.